# Parallax with Many Assets and Large One

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, parallax

I am trying to create a landing page that has a parallax effect. The problem is that when scrolling, the assets seem to move at less than 15 fps. In this performance, the parallax effect is not noticeable. The object inside the element bg_container is more than 10000px in height.

What is wrong with my code or is there a better implementation for this. This is the temporary site of my site: http://royvon.therookieblog.com/

Here the version 1 of my code in which the objects are moved within the window scroll event:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {

            var bg_speed = 0.7;
            var tree_speed = 0.8;
            var mid_speed = 0.8;
            var fast_speed = 1.0;

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('#bg_container').css('top',(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px');
                $('#map_1home_container').css('top',(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px');
                $('#map_2playGround_container').css('top',(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px');
                $('#map_3camp_container').css('top',(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px');
                //AND SOME 15 OBEJCTS HERE
            });

        });
```

Here is the version 2 of my code that uses setTimeout to move the assets:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {

            var scrollTimer = null;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if (scrollTimer) {
                    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);   // clear any previous pending timer
                }
                scrollTimer = setTimeout(moveObjects, 25);   // set new timer
            });

        });

        function moveObjects() {    
            var bg_speed = 0.7;
            var tree_speed = 0.8;
            var mid_speed = 0.8;
            var fast_speed = 1.0;

            var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('#bg_container').stop(true, true).animate({'top':(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px'}, 25);
            $('#map_1home_container').stop(true, true).css({'top':(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px'},25);
            $('#map_2playGround_container').css('top',(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px');
            $('#map_3camp_container').css('top',(0-(scrolled*bg_speed))+'px');
            //AND SOME other assets here
        }
```

In version 2, I have tried changing the number in setTimeout. I also tried in version 2 changing the .css to .animate but the performance is still the same.

For version 1, Firefox and Chrome seems to display the parallax in less than 15fps but in internet explorer 9 and 10, it's very smooth.

I have tried viewing both versions in Chrome for android and the performance was catastrophic.

Is there something that can be done in this code? Or I just tell the client leave this idea?

Comment: Hi James, I believe the problem is caused by the browser doing continual redraws each time 1px is scrolled on the page. Perhaps think if you could paralax the elements in a different order and keep the main background fixed? I've seen this slowness happen before - but I dont have the solution.

Comment: thanks for the reply david. yes, when the background is static, there is a significant improvement but of course this would not be a solution for them hehe thanks for the reply...

Comment: Well James I was thinking perhaps there is a way to keep the background static but still give a parallax effect with the scrolling of the other elements to give the same effect... :/ hmmm

Comment: the trees and signs must go with the large background. The background is the slowest to move, the trees and signs are a little faster than the background. So making the bg static is not an option here. :(

Comment: how about turn the background and all assets into .svg files - this should reduce the amount of compute time significantly

Comment: have the png files as an IE fallback

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve performance on my parallax scroll script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685928/how-can-i-improve-performance-on-my-parallax-scroll-script)

Comment: hi @gjeck, i think his implementation of parallax is different from mine. I am trying to move my assets in almost different rate. thanks for your reply by the way...